# Add multiple variables into one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if variables is the right term to use here.
So, I made a block in Concrete5 to allow hours of certain departments to be listed.

This is an example script I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Saturdayopen").datetimepicker({
"pickDate":false,
"pickTime":true,
"useMinutes":true,
"useSeconds":false,
"useCurrent":false,
"showToday":false,
"useStrict":false,
"sideBySide":false,
"minuteStepping":1,
"minDate":"",
"defaultDate":"",
"icons ":{
"time":"glyphicon glyphicon-time",
"date":"glyphicon glyphicon-calendar",
"up":"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up",
"down":"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"},
"language":"en",
"disabledDates":[],
"enabledDates":[],
"daysOfWeekDisabled":[]});
    });
</script>
```

The issue is I need to use the same script each time for each day of the week twice. So I have 14 of these scripts in the same file. Is there any way for me to condense the code into one script?

For example, on this line:

```
$("#Saturdayopen").datetimepicker({
```

Is there any way to also add #Saturdayclosed, #Sundayopen, etc etc etc?

Comment: Anybody got any tips? c:

Comment: how do you find that current day is open or close, is there any logic to it ?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have to do anything with Concrete5, but it has to do with Javascript.

<strike>Variables isn't the right term here, you're looking for a way to add multiple elements to your jQuery selector. jQuery uses CSS selectors, so you'd do the same as you would in CSS: string 'em together with commas:</strike>

```
$("#Saturdayopen, #Sundayopen, #etcetera").datetimepicker({...
```

#### Response to comment by it0ken:

That's probably due to limitations of the `.datetimepicker()` plugin you're using. You could easily fix by using a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop:

```
var days = ["#Saturdayopen", "#Sundayopen", "#etc"];

for(var i = 0; i < days.length; ++i){

    $(days[i]).datetimepicker({
        //options
    });

}
```

You probably could also can get rid of some default parameters in your code examples, that should trim it down a whole lot.

Comment: I tried doing this, which is where the initial question came in. Using the commas only allow for whatever element is first in the string. IE: Your example would leave Saturdayopen functioning, but the datetimepicker wouldn't even initiate for any other open/closing for the days.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `enabledDates` and `daysOfWeekDisabled` to control which days are enabled?

If your goal is to condense the code, you could declare some defaults that get reused instead of creating 14 anonymous objects.  This may be more flexible than doing batch processing, unless the the properties are always the same for each `datetimepicker`.

```js
var DateTimePicker = {
  //return a new copy of the defaults
  Defaults: function() {
    return {
      "pickDate": false,
      "pickTime": true,
      "useMinutes": true,
      "useSeconds": false,
      "useCurrent": false,
      "showToday": false,
      "useStrict": false,
      "sideBySide": false,
      "minuteStepping": 1,
      "minDate": "",
      "defaultDate": "",
      "icons ": {
        "time": "glyphicon glyphicon-time",
        "date": "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar",
        "up": "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up",
        "down": "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"
      },
      "language": "en",
      "disabledDates": [],
      "enabledDates": [],
      "daysOfWeekDisabled": []
    }
  }
}

/*
JSON.stringify [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify] 
prints the results of a JSON object so we can view the results
$.extend [https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/] will merge any override settings into the defaults
*/

//lets set Saturday as open
$("#Saturdayopen").html(JSON.stringify($.extend(DateTimePicker.Defaults(), {
  enabledDates: ["Saturday"]
})));

//now lets try setting Saturday as closed
$("#Saturdayclosed").html(JSON.stringify($.extend(DateTimePicker.Defaults(), {
  daysOfWeekDisabled: ["Saturday"]
})));

/*daysOfWeekDisabled
using this in your code would look like
$("#Saturdayopen").datetimepicker($.extend(DateTimePicker.Defaults(), {enabledDates:["Saturday"]}));
$("#Saturdayclosed").datetimepicker($.extend(DateTimePicker.Defaults(), {daysOfWeekDisabled:["Saturday"]}));
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Saturday Open:
  <div id="Saturdayopen"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div>Saturday Closed:
  <div id="Saturdayclosed"></div>
</div>
```